# Website: Error 403 on Symlinks Pointing Outside of Webroot

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, symbolic-link, httpd

I am trying to create a website in the latest version of Fedora Linux. I want the website to point to something in my home directory. After doing some Googling, I can acheive this with a SymLink. The problem I'm having is that I'm receiving a "Forbidden" Message

I do NOT have an Apache config file for some reason. But I read that I was supposed to configure the httpd.conf equivalent. So without further ado, here is my https.config file in addition to my .htaccess. I can't get the quote tag to work so you'll just have to read it in normal text on pastebin.

/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
https://pastebin.com/j4Lvqy3q

.htaccess
https://pastebin.com/HhfDcbg5

I created the symlink

```
sudo ln -s /home/archive /var/www/html/
```

Once I have configured the files, I changed permissions on the directories

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /home/archive
sudo chown -R archive:archive /home/archive
```

and restarted httpd

```
sudo systemctl restart httpd
```

It didn't work. It has every reason to work and I followed all the instructions, yet it failed. So I decided to play around with it. I noticed that the symlink works if it points to a directory WITHIN the webroot. But it only fails when pointing to a directory outside of it.

So the symlinks themselves work, it's just something to do with permissions either in the config file or the filesystem. The above steps should have taken care of that so I don't know what else to do.

Oh, and just for fun I tried

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache /home/archive
sudo systemctl restart httpd
```

That didn't work either

Comment: What was happened with physical/original non symlinked directory `/var/www/html/` ? It won't be overridden with symlink as you did. (BTW, never use 777 permissions on exposed to the internet servers)

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean. The /var/www/html directory has 755 permissions. It is also owned by the root user and group. I don’t think that is a problem because I can access my normal non symlink files and folders. I used 777 for the non webroot direcory because I don’t care about security. I just want it to work. One I get it to work, THEN i’ll worry about security.

Comment: I noticed something interesting. I copied the archive directory to the archive directory to /archiveroot and added in entries and a symlink to the arhiveroot directory. When i try to access the archive symlink, the error says I don’t have permissions to access archive/index.html. When i try to access the archiveroot symlink, it only says I cannot access archive root but without the index.html. Not sure if that helps. Just fooling around and gathering information

Comment: Add `Allow from all` and `Require all granted` to the section `<Directory "/var/www/html/archive">...</Directory>`

Comment: I’m sorry but that did not work

Comment: Is it supposed to be Allow from all or Allow from * ? Either way it did not work

Comment: Did you add `Require all granted` ? By the way I can't see you included in your apache's config enabled sites. You need to specify at least default virtual server.

Comment: I added Require all granted to each of the <directories> in the httpd.conf file. Even restarted httpd itself. No luck.

Comment: Do you have `Options +FollowSymLinks` set?

Comment: Should i be adding all this to the httpd.conf, .htaccess or both?

Comment: I've been playing around with the two config files. Can you review them and tell me what I'm doing wrong. At this point I feel like I'm throwing everything at the wall and praying that something sticks. It is extremely frustrating since all the tutorials make it look easy.

Here is my .htaccess file
https://pastebin.com/JQnahpkH

Here is mt httpd.conf file
https://pastebin.com/6M6d7pn3